# Rasa chatbot won't answer to some messages

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am building a chatbot using rasa_core and rasa_nlu. As of now I am simply deploying it on my Ubuntu shell (I am using Windows 10). Now my problem is that from time to time, the bot won't answer to my messages: it directly goes to the 'Action_listen' action. After this, the only way to have the bot work normally again is to exit and relaunch it.

Strangely, I cannot derive any pattern to explain what causes this problem, and the very same conversation history can both cause this problem or no problem at all. That makes debugging specifically difficult as I cannot reproduce this problem on demand.

Nothing appears. I have changed rasa's code so that it prints the outputs of the intent recognition and of _get_next_action in processor.py. The output of the intent recognition does appear normally, the ouput of _get_next_action is:

```
Action('action_listen')
```

Any idea what might be the cause and the solution ?

Thank you for your help,

Best,

Vincent.

Comment: Is there some area of your code that has been identified as the likely culprit?  Show it, and detail why you think so,  It will be difficult for people to respond without seeing your code.

Comment: Well not really unfortunately. I have tried to deep dive into rasa's code but since the problem is not reproducible on demand, that's quite difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me in the initial stages.

My issue was that my intents were quite confusing for the bot. For example, two contradicting statements had the same intent or I had too many things under the same intent. I fixed this by changing my intents and entities.

If you post your stories, someone can help. It is really tough to know more without information.